# label to store <div id="test">variable content</div> (with html tags) with html tags

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Cant seem to get this to work, for some reason it wont output the newdiv to my asp control (Label1) id like my label to store variable content (with html tags)

I also get auto post back even altho its set to false (not very good with java/jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('button').click(function () {
                var x = $('textarea').val();
                $('textarea').val('');
                var label = $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>");
                var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'test');
                $('#test1').append(newdiv);
                var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                label.text(serializer.serializeToString(newdiv));
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea style="border: 0" cols="77" rows="2">Write Something....</textarea>
<button>Post Message</button>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<div id="test1">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

need to figure out how to set the Text of the asp control rather than Label with my jquery:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Why dont you just insert a html input button instead of asp:Button if you are not executing any server code when clicking the button.
Also in jQuery you cannot reference to a button tag, it needs to be "input"

Comment: It seems like when using a button element will automatically submit the form to the server, try using <input type='button'/> instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle here - you have tons of stuff wrong with your code, but I will stick to the big stuff to start. Then you can sort out little stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/4BEGs/1/

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    //store text area value
    var x = $('#mytextarea').val();
    //clear text area
    $('#mytextarea').val('');
    //enter textarea value into a new div
    var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'test');
    $('#test1').append(newdiv);

    //Get html of newdiv, including itself
    var html = $('<div>').append(newdiv.clone()).remove().html(); 
    //Escape the html of newdiv so that we can display it on the page
    escapedhtml = $('<div/>').text(html).html();
    //Set label to be new html
    $("#mylabel").html(escapedhtml);
});
```

Your code most likely causes a postback because you have runat="server" in your asp tags. As an earlier post pointed out, don't use an ASP control if you don't need it. Just write `<input type="button" value="mybutton" />` straight into your aspx page instead of relying on asp controls.

Your code is in an anonymous function and doesn't need to be. Your code should execute inside a $(document).ready.

It is good practice to store jquery variables like `var label = $('#label')` using a money sign so you know it is a jQuery object. `var $label = $('#label')`

Hope this gets you on your way.

Comment: the bit u said u dont know what im trying to do and the commented out part at the bottom is me trying to put <div id=test>textarea content</div> into my asp Label1 control!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have the $(document).ready call inside the click event handler. All you are actually doing is binding that when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            var x = $('textarea').val();
            $('textarea').val('');
            var label = $("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>");
            var newdiv = $("<div></div>").html(x).attr('id', 'test');
            $('#test1').append(newdiv);
            var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
            label.text(serializer.serializeToString(newdiv));
            return false;
        });
    });
```

You should bind the click event on document.ready, not the oposite. First make sure that your function is called when you click the button.

Do you want to do this on every button click? I suggest you to give your button an id and change

```
 $("button").click(function () {
```

to

```
$('#<%= myButton.ClientID %>').click(function () {
```

Comment: still makes no difference i get post back regardless and it still wont out put the newdiv to my label

Comment: @Garrith Graham - did you give your button an id? I'll edit my post with more details.

Comment: also this is just a test i will set the id later but for now wont output

Comment: there is only one button in the contentplace holder and its my html button it really doesnt need a button id set to it does it? I know its good practice but its the main function i need working

Comment: the button works fine and so does adding the div to my page with the content from my textarea the only thing not working is sending the div +contents to the label (html tags included)

Comment: Ok, you need to stop it from posting back :) I'm pretty sure you are losing the value on postback.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh i dont know how lol but nah its abit of a slow machine and be4 i lose the div content on post back the label never changes so there is still something wrong with the function

Comment: hmmm it seems its the label thats actually doing the postback but u cant set an asp control not to run at server can you?

Comment: why are you using a label? use a html control and you can use webservices if you need server-side action.